# How do I add a link to the category in menu?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes, navigation

Now this might be a dumb question, but it's not obvious. Seriously. I have a menu with node/ID links as paths, but I also need one link to the category in the menu. I know that pasting in absolute urls or slugs is not a good idea. But how do I do it otherwise?

Comment: By 'category' do you mean taxonomy page? Since those aren't nodes (assuming you're in D6, not sure about D7) the path alias is the only way to reference them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a root link, one beginning with a slash? such as /taxonomy/term/34

Comment: or of course: /whatever/your/alias/is/to/that/term

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in absolute's.  Is the Category a taxonomy?  If so you could just link to the taxonomy page.  Want a more custom view, use Views with an arguement.

Comment: I know I can pass in absolutes, but if I move the website later to a different domain, it will break.